# Add a 0 digit at the start of the single digit value in date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here, I want to change the date format while typing where when i type 1/1/2018, it has to change to 01/01/2018 while typing and every time the 0 has to be added in date while I'm giving the '/' character.
Here is the code which changes the first value on click function where i want to make it reactive while typing in which the '/' differentiates the date and month.
Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/qpdVU/

```
    $('#date').blur(function () {
            var collector = $('#date').val();
            collector = collector.split("/");
            if (collector[0].length != 2) {
                if (collector[0].length == 1) {
                    collector[0] = "0" + collector[0];
                }
            }

    $('#date').val(collector.join('/'));
});

Date: <input type="text" id="date" name="date" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check invalid date using `new Date()` then add `0` to make the date appear the way you want.

```js
$('#date').blur(function() {
  var collector = $('#date').val();
  if (new Date(collector).toString() === 'Invalid Date') {
    alert('Date is not entered properly');
  }
  collector = collector.split("/");
  if (collector[0].length == 1) {
    collector[0] = "0" + collector[0];
  }
  if (collector[1].length == 1) {
    collector[1] = "0" + collector[1];
  }
  $('#date').val(collector.join('/'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i want. Can you please edit this in my fiddle given above and can you make it reactive like when '/' is pressed it has to generate the 0 which indicates that the particular date or month is over

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Agarwal. Can you help me out with the change event

Comment: Can I know the name of the function here